# "Inept" Vs. "Inapt"

Tags: differences

I was writing a complaint letter and I wrote a line

> He is inept in his profession.

Someone corrected me and said it should be ***inapt*** and not ***inept***.

A google search revealed that both the words *inept* and *inapt* could be relevant in such a sentence. But I think I didn't completely understand the difference between the two. Can anyone explain the difference between them? Maybe through an example?

---

Edit:
By saying "He is inept in his profession", my intention was to make my sentence sounds like: *He is not very good in his profession, or is unable to do his work properly or is not well versed*.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to say what you intended your sentence to mean, and what a couple of [dictionaries](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available/2574#2574) (not a simple Google search) tell you about the meaning of each word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until about the 18th century, **inapt** and **inept** use to have an overlap: both meant

(OED)

> **inept-> 1.a. Not adapted or adaptable; not suited for (†to) a purpose; without aptitude; unsuitable, unfit.** *archaic*.
>
> 1692   J. Ray Misc. Disc. Dissolution World 142   *The Air..would contain but few nitrous Particles, and so be inept to maintain the Fire.*
>
> **inapt -> 1. Not adapted to the purpose or occasion; unsuitable, inappropriate, inapposite.**
>
> 1885   Law Times 78 242/1   *The words..being altogether inapt to express more than one devolution of title.*

This is the current meaning of "inapt".

However, you will note that "inept" is now archaic in this sense, and we should disregard the meaning above.

The meaning of "**inept**" is now

MW:

> **inept** adjective
>
> **Definition of inept**
>
> 1: generally incompetent : BUNGLING -> inept leadership
>
> 2: lacking in fitness or aptitude : UNFIT -> inept at sports
>
> 3: not suitable to the time, place, or occasion : inappropriate often to an absurd degree -> an inept metaphor
>
> 4: lacking sense or reason : FOOLISH

Comment: To me the current meaning of inept is awkward, clumsy, not skilled at the task one is attempting, whether it is pounding a nail or doing brain surgery. See https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=inept.

Comment: @Xanne: You are right, of course. I can only put my error down to "cut and paste". I have corrected it.